Changes in firm cost structures and its affect on overall markets

DISCLAIMER ALL DIAGRAMS REPRESENT COMPETIVE MARKETS AND FIRMS
I came across this image in the economics book I was reading and it made perfect sense to me. The specific tax imposition increases the variable costs for each good therefore the cost curve shift in resulting in a lower out put levels. If we then extended this to all firms in the market then we would also see supply in the market shift in
However I then also came across this image

This image confused as me as yet again input prices have increased however the output levels for each firm has increased which seems contradictory, I know that a firm needs to have an output at the profit max level so this condition is still being met, but the fact that quantity increases in the scenario seems contradictory. I know sometimes you can employ a factor of production that is more costly but increases productivity, but in which case you would not expect the costs to go up either.
What was even more confusing was how in the market this would reflect as an increase in demand which made little sense to me as yet again if input prices increased supply would surely decrease similar to the first image?
